# squid /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, squid

I have a LAN X.X.X.X/24 and a gateway on which we were told to run Squid.
In the same LAN we have the commercial department and software developers.

We have a production version of our website on public IP Y.Y.Y.Y
and a development version on a different private LAN Z.Z.Z.Z/24

Developers in X.X.X.X/24 need to do HTTP requests to the two different versions of our website.
They used to do it changing /etc/hosts accordingly.

Now we have transparent squid in the middle that resolves DNS before HTTP-requesting, so all requests end up in the public, production version of our website.

I do not know how squid internals that allow transparent proxying work, but is there a workaround that allows only developers' machines to control locally on their machines where their requests will go?
Something like "do not DNS-query if for these, say X.X.X.X/29, machines"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Squid as a tansparent proxy does *not* see the IP address of the target server - it only sees the host name and then uses DNS for address resolution itself.

But there must be a "transparent proxy" rule somewhere on your router / Internet gateway for the transparent proxy to work. You need to change it to: "Do not use transparent proxy if target IP is Z.Z.Z.Z/24" - so your development servers will be accessed directly without proxy. This way you can still use your `/etc/hosts` trick.